# storageInitializer InitContainer not starting in Kserve InferenceService

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow

I'm trying out KServe. I've followed installation instructions as per the official [docs](https://kserve.github.io/website/0.8/admin/serverless/). I'm trying to create a sample HTTP InferenceService exactly same as [this](https://kserve.github.io/website/modelserving/v1beta1/tensorflow/#create-the-http-inferenceservice). by doing `kubectl apply -f tensorflow.yaml`

```
apiVersion: "serving.kserve.io/v1beta1"
kind: "InferenceService"
metadata:
  name: "flower-sample"
spec:
  predictor:
    tensorflow:
      storageUri: "gs://kfserving-samples/models/tensorflow/flowers"
```

This yaml creates an `InferenceService` and assosicated deployments, replicaset, and a pod. However, the InferenceService remains in `Unknown` state, upon investiagating, I found that 1 container (queue-proxy container) out of 2 wasn't able to do Readiness probe, `Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503` .

Upon further investigation, I saw the following logs from `kserve-container` container

`2022-04-07 17:14:46.482205: E tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:365] FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a filesystem access error: Could not find base path /mnt/models for servable flower-sample with error Not found: /mnt/models not found`

So I understood models not present. I manually downloaded the same `gs://kfserving-samples/models/tensorflow/flowers` and copied in the correct path. Finally InferenceService started working.

**But I want to avoid doing this manual copying of models into pod's container.**

It should ideally be done by init-container - `storage-initializer` which is missing in my   case.

I did `kubectl describe flower-sample-predictor-default-00001-deployment-5db9d7d9fgqfn4` and **I don't see any `initContainers` section.**

All these workloads are running in kserve namespace. I've a configmap `inferenceservice-config` which has the following (default) `storageInitializer`

```
{
    "image" : "kserve/storage-initializer:v0.8.0",
    "memoryRequest": "100Mi",
    "memoryLimit": "1Gi",
    "cpuRequest": "100m",
    "cpuLimit": "1"
}
```

But still when I do `kubectl apply -f tensorflow.yaml` I'm facing the same error. Could anyone help me on how to fix this ?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I have a similar problem